# Duplicate TreeView Schema is VS Code Extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing a VS Code extension that implements a custom viewsContainer. It is activated in an `onView:` event specified in the package JSON.

This all works great, and my view pulls in data from a static JSON file and does add each node to the view.

My JSON is strucutured like this:

```
{
  "name": "root",
  "children": {
    "Child1": [
      { "id": "childId1", "name": "childName1" },
      { "id": "childId2", "name": "childId2" }
    ],
    "Child2": [
        { "id": "childId1", "name": "childName1" },
        { "id": "childId2", "name": "childId2" }
    ],
    "Child3": [
        { "id": "childId1", "name": "childName1" },
        { "id": "childId2", "name": "childId2" }
    ],
    "Child4": [
        { "id": "childId1", "name": "childName1" },
        { "id": "childId2", "name": "childId2" }
    ]
  }
}
```

and my class that is registered as a treeviewprovider in `extension.ts` is:

```
import * as vscode from "vscode";

import * as validateMenuItems from "./validateMenuItems.json";

export class ValidateMenuProvider
  implements vscode.TreeDataProvider<ValidateMenu> {
  private _onDidChangeTreeData: vscode.EventEmitter<
    ValidateMenu | undefined
  > = new vscode.EventEmitter<ValidateMenu | undefined>();
  readonly onDidChangeTreeData: vscode.Event<ValidateMenu | undefined> = this
    ._onDidChangeTreeData.event;

  constructor() {}

  refresh(): void { 
    this._onDidChangeTreeData.fire();
  }

  getTreeItem(element: ValidateMenu): vscode.TreeItem {
    if(element) {
      console.log(`element: ${element}`);
      return element;
    }

    return element;
  }

  getChildren(element?: ValidateMenu): Thenable<ValidateMenu[]> {
    if (element) {
      return Promise.resolve([]);
    } else {
      return Promise.resolve(this.getValidateMenu());
    }
  }

  private getValidateMenu(): ValidateMenu[] {
    const toMenu = (
      menuTitle: string,
      collapsibleState: vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState
    ): ValidateMenu => {
      return new ValidateMenu(menuTitle, collapsibleState);
    };

    let menuItems: any = []; 
    let menuHeadings: any = validateMenuItems.children;

    let j: number = 0;
    for (var i in menuHeadings) {
      // send the parent as a menu item
      if (menuHeadings[i] !== null && typeof menuHeadings[i] === "object") {
        let firstChildLabel: string = Object.keys(validateMenuItems.children)[
          j
        ];
        let parentMenuItem = toMenu(
          firstChildLabel,
          vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.Collapsed 
        );
        menuItems.push(parentMenuItem);

        // send each child object to the view
        for (var k = 0; k < menuHeadings[i].length; k++) {
          if (
            menuHeadings[i][k] !== null &&
            typeof menuHeadings[i][k] === "object"
          ) {
            let secondChildLabel: string = menuHeadings[i][k].name;
            let childMenuItem = toMenu(
              secondChildLabel,
              vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.None
            );
            menuItems.push(childMenuItem);
          } else {
            return [];
          }
        }
      } else {
        return [];
      }
      j++;
    }

    return menuItems;
  }
}

export class ValidateMenu extends vscode.TreeItem {
  constructor(
    public readonly label: string,
    public readonly collapsibleState: vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState,
    public readonly command?: vscode.Command
  ) {
    super(label, collapsibleState);
  }
}
```

What this does is put every item in the JSON into the view, the first set of object under `root.children` as collapsed items, and their respective children as non-expandable/collapsible.

However, for each of the expandable items, if I click to expand it, the entire rest of the JSON schema is repeated underneath it.

From stepping through and watching the call stack frames it appears that the requried `getChildren()` method is first initially called when the provider is registered, and at each expand event.

My question is - since `getChildren()` requires a `<Thenable>`, where am I going wrong with my implementation with `getValidateMenu()` that will avoid duplicating the schema on the collapsed objects, and actually group it's child objects within the collapsed item?

Do the immediate `root.children` items need to have a command that calls some kind of `onclick` sort of method, that gets `this` and reveals its children?

Any pointers from those more familiar greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not implementing [`getChildren()`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TreeDataProvider.getChildren) correctly. It's documented like this:

> Get the children of `element` or root if no element is passed.

What your implementation seems to do instead is "return a flat list of *all* tree items when no `element` is passed, and an empty list otherwise".

You need to actually return the children of the requested `element` (and only the immediate children, instead of returning the whole tree at once for the root element).

The official [Tree View Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/tree-view-sample) might be worth checking out.

Comment: Thanks @Gama11 I knew my implementation was wrong, just unsure of the source of the problem. I was working off of MS's Tree View Sample from GitHub, and following their approach was what confused me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The simplest approach would probably be to add a `children` field to your `TreeItem` subclass and make the data structure recursive that way. Then you can just return `element.children` in `getChildren()`.

Comment: @Gamma11 I get what you're saying but I keep running into issues with '`Promise<ValidateMenu[]> is not assignable to type ValidateMenu` even if I add an optional `children` field. Is your suggestion to change the implementation of the `getValidateMenu()` method and just have it return the `ValidateMenu` object as the resolved promise? The type checking is really frustrating to wrap my head around

Comment: Honestly, I would probably just return the data directly instead of bothering with promises and Thenables, since it seems like you already have all the data at the time the `getChildren()` call happens anyway. Note that the return type is a `ProivderResult`, which can be a Thenable _or_ the raw data. https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ProviderResult

Comment: @Gamma11 Just read through that. However, if I set `getChildren()` to just return `element.children` or just `element`, I get this error: https://pasteboard.co/I7Gmhze.png  and having a hard time understanding what the compiler actually means. Can you try to explain? Does it just mean it wants an array of `ValidateMenu` instead of a single objecT?

Comment: The return type needs to be `ValidateMenu[]`, not `ValidateMenu`.

Comment: @Gamma11 last question - so how does the provider know what to look for the first time it calls `getTreeItem()`? That's what's really lost me. I tried passing it `validateMenuItems.children`, and it barks about it not having any properties in common with `TreeItem`. Every time I try something, there's a type problem

Comment: I'm not sure why you would ever need to call `getTreeItem()` yourself? In this case the implementation is really just a dummy `return element` since your `T` extends `vscode.TreeItem` anyway.

Comment: So redesigning my implementation of `getValidateMenu()` is where the need is, right?

Comment: I mean, yeah, that seems to be where all the work is happening. :)

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. I'll try to figure this out and post an edited answer once I stop banging my head into my desk

Answer (score 1):

Even I struggled with this for quite a while, found the github repo shared by the OP in another question. I think it's worthwhile mentioning it here so that others are benefited.

https://github.com/trebleCode/dxdevcheck/blob/master/src/validateMenu.ts

The key for me was to add `children` field to my `TreeItem` subclass as mentioned by @Gama11 in the comments.

Comment: so much this! Thanks for adding my repo link